# Apache Kafka Brokers (Cluster): exited with code 1 on docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm learning docker and trying to setup a Kafka Cluster with 3 Zookeepers instances and 3 brokers.

Sometimes the brokers runs fine, but sometimes they are exiting with status 1 and the logs shows the following message:

> kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID
> p2ouSB1rTKyUddeL26jpxg doesn't match stored clusterId
> Some(4QuK9rOmTleiRryAOA5zwA) in meta.properties. The broker is trying
> to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.

I searched a lot before post this question and nothing I founded resolved the issue.

First a though it was the volumes I was using to persist Zookeeper data and logs on the host, but now that I got ride of them, I'm still getting the same error and have no idea of how to setup a Cluster Id through docker-compose and share it among all brokers. Is there a fix to this?

I'm running `Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636` and `Docker Compose version v2.1.1` on `Windows`.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  zookeeper-1:
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services.yml
      service: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  zookeeper-2:
    hostname: zookeeper-2
    container_name: zookeeper-2
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services.yml
      service: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2182:2182'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2182

  zookeeper-3:
    hostname: zookeeper-3
    container_name: zookeeper-3
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services.yml
      service: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2183:2183'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2183

  broker-1:
    container_name: broker-1
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services.yml
      service: broker
    ports:
      - '19092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2182,zookeeper-3:2183'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:19092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker-1:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3

  broker-2:
    container_name: broker-2
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services.yml
      service: broker
    ports:
      - '29092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2182,zookeeper-3:2183'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker-2:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker-2:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3

  broker-3:
    container_name: broker-3
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services.yml
      service: broker
    ports:
      - '39092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2182,zookeeper-3:2183'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker-3:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:39092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker-3:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
      - broker-2
      - broker-3
    ports:
      - '8083:8083'
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker-1:9092,broker-2:9092,broker-3:9092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.2.1.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: 'io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor'
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: 'io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/connect-plugins'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.2.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
      - broker-2
      - broker-3
      - connect
    ports:
      - '9021:9021'
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker-1:9092,broker-2:9092,broker-3:9092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      #CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: 'http://ksqldb-server:8088'
      #CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: 'http://localhost:8088'
      #CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
```

This is my services.yml file:

```yaml
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.1
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      # KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

Comment: At a glance, yours looks OK - but evidently there's a problem if you're getting an error :) Have you tried [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/master/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml)? I would start with that and then work backwards towards your version until you find the problem.

Comment: Are you sure `extends` supports **appending** environment variables instead of overwriting them? Also, there is not much benefit to running multiple Zookeeper or broker on a single host

Comment: @OneCricketeer if one fails for any reason, there are others to take actions, that's the reason. I'm not sure, but I think extends is merging the environments.

Comment: But it is still a single point of failure (your host). Running multiple of them are competing for the same hard-drive and memory resources. In any case, you may want to try changing the zookeeper peer and leader ports to be different for each of those...

Comment: @RobinMoffatt That file wont work on Mac with `network_mode: host`, or even removing it will cause problems with all the usage of `localhost`